# How can I get my iPhone to consistently apply or ignore auto-corrections based on my response?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 4S (Black, 32 GB, AT&T) running iOS 5.0.1, but I previously saw this issue on my jail-broken iPhone 3GS while it was running 5.0 and 4.3.3. This iPhone 4S is not jail-broken, nor has it been jail-broken in the past.

This occurs only sometimes. While I am typing and an auto-correction pops up, if I click on the auto-correction, it substitutes the text immediately instead of disabling that particular correction.

Is this a bug, or is it possible that I have a setting somewhere that causes it to act in this fashion? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 2):

Non-jailbroken iOS doesn't give much room for auto-corrections adjustment. Settings > General > Keyboard, is about all there is.

It is possible that it is a bug on your system, but on my 4S (5.1), I duplicated your problem only when I didn't tap the balloon itself.

Comment: When you say that you "missed the balloon," do you mean that you clicked entirely outside of it?

Comment: Yes (and no). Out of it enough that the screen/phone recognizes it as out of the balloon.

Comment: Clicking outside the balloon doesn't seem to duplicate this for me - at least, not 100% of the time. And clicking inside the balloon seems to sometimes still replace it.

Comment: What kind of case do you have on it? I also edited the first part out of my answer.

Comment: Are you referring to the physical case protecting my device? It's an Otterbox Defender (the newer, 4S model rather than the model originally made for the iPhone 4).

Comment: There is a chance that your screen protector is causing a problem. Make sure that the Defender's screen cover is the ONLY screen cover on your phone. You could always try removing the case, and trying it then.

Comment: Ah, that is possible. It is the only screen protector I am using. I will try removing the case and see if I can reproduce the issue.